# Prove that $b^2 \in \langle a \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $8$. Assume that there exists $a \in G$ such that $|a|=4$ and that no element of $G$ has order $8$. Explain why $\langle a \rangle \lhd G$. Assume that $b \notin \langle a \rangle$. Prove that $b^2 \in \langle a \rangle$.

I am not sure why $\langle a \rangle \lhd G$.

Proof: Let $|G|=8$.Assume that there exists $a \in G$ such that $|a|=4$ and that no element of $G$ has order $8$. Assume that $b \notin \langle a \rangle$.

Then $b \neq e, a, a^2, a^3$. And I don't know what to do next.

Comment: **Hint**: The subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ has index $2$ in $G$, so must be normal.

Comment: For the second part, note that $G$ has order $8$, so it has $8$ elements. Use the fact that $b \notin \langle a \rangle$, and then ask yourself how many elements $\langle b \rangle$ could have if $G$ has $8$ elements. Use this to deduce the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $H < G$ such that $[G:H]=2$, $H\triangleleft G$, because, for any $a \in G\setminus H$,
$$
aH\cap H = \emptyset, \text{ and } |aH| = |H| \Rightarrow aH = G\setminus H
$$
Similarly, $Ha = G\setminus H$ and so,
$$
aH = Ha \quad\forall a\in G
$$

To answer your question : If $H:= \langle a\rangle$, then $\overline{b} \in G/H$, and since $|G/H| = 2$, we have that $\overline{b}^2 = \overline{e}$, and so $b^2 \in H$

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful  if you can try for more general thing (which is in contrast much easier to see) :

If $H\unlhd G$ and $g\notin H$ and $|G:H|=n$, then $g^n\in H$.

Consider $gH$ as an element in $G/H$, as $g\notin H$ , we see that $gH\neq 1H \in G/H$

As $H\unlhd G$ we see that $G/H$ is a group and as it is given $|G:H|=n$ we see that :

> every non identity element of $G/H$ has order $n$

As $gH\in G/H$ is non identity element we end up with saying $(gH)^n=1H$

As $H\unlhd G$, we see that $gH=Hg$ i,e., $gHgH=ggHH=g^2H$ more generally, $(gH)^n=g^nH$

As we have seen above that $(gH)^n=1H$ we end up with some thing like $(gH)^n=g^nH=1H$

$g^nH=1H$ implies that $g^n\in H $ as required.

Coming to your special case (as you are able to see $\big<a\big>\unlhd G$) :

$b\notin \big<a\big>\unlhd G$ and as $|G : \big<a\big>|=2$ we see that $b^2\in \big<a\big>$